# nsmutablearray not giving proper count

Tags: objective-c

Hi i am having an nsmutablearray like NSMutableArray *arr; i did something like below

```
NSNull *myNull=[NSNull null];
 for(int i=0;i<10;[self.arr insertObject:myNull atIndex:i],++i);
```

then i replace all the object with some value

```
for(int i=0;i<[arr1 count];++i)
{ 
[self.arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex::i]];
}
```

where arr1 has some real value but my problem is there i am getting 20 objects instead of 10. It should have been 10. please let me know where is my problem and what will be the solution. thanks in advance

Comment: no it'l give only 10 objects...some where else you went wrong i think so.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  If replaceObjectAtIndex:i where i>[arr count] you'll get an exception.    Sunny's right -- there is something else happening here, like maybe the first loop getting executed twice, which would do it.

Comment: Can you log your arr with 20 objects?

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing in `arr` using `arr1` then you should use
like

```
for(int i=0;i<[arr count];++i)
{ 
    [self.arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: no this is not an issue.beacause if the arr1 having more thatn 10 elements then it'l crash.

Comment: but if arr1 contains more than 10 , than?? so if you want add 10 items only than use [arr count].

Comment: that's why i clearly mensioned that if more tha 10 elements then it'l crash...that is wrong coding but in his that one not an issues .

Comment: in my case arr1 will always contain 10 objects  .
can you please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: maybe the first loop getting executed twice